# How to Get only number from string mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, numbers

I have a column called `Equipment` in my table that contains something like this: `store(2)`

I need to create a new column and select only the number from the text otherwise we put `1`.

Example:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 
CASE WHEN 'equipment contains number then put this number' ELSE 'we put 1' END AS Quantity FROM my_table.
```

Thanks.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function for this.

```
SELECT IF(REGEXP_SUBSTR('store(2)','[0-9]+') != '', REGEXP_SUBSTR('store(2)','[0-9]+'), 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to put that in if condition . If the the colmun contains number we put that number Else  we put 1

Comment: I tried you code but i got null value  when i try to change the string without number like this ( store ). it should return 1.

Comment: this is my code: SELECT IF(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Equipment,"[0-9]+") = '', 1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Equipment,"[0-9]+")) as quantity from ta_a

Comment: and this is the result i got : 
NULL
2
NULL
NULL
NULL
20

Comment: Yes he put Null instead of 1 . how can i add the ISNULL Function in my code ?

Comment: `SELECT IF(ISNULL(REGEXP_SUBSTR('store(2)',"[0-9]+") ) OR REGEXP_SUBSTR('store(2)',"[0-9]+") != '',  REGEXP_SUBSTR('store(2)',"[0-9]+"), 1);`

Comment: Sorry i got the same result null value :
NULL
2
NULL
NULL
NULL
20

Comment: Yes i'm using phpmyadmin already . the probelm is when i test with a string like "store" it works and he gave 1 but when i use my Equipement colmun instead it doesn't work and he gave me null

Comment: No all rows with values

Comment: I used the last code you send me but I deleted the ISNULL function and it works.